# Python Code to grant access privilege's for users in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm, psycopg2

I have writte a python code that would give access privileges (Grant & Revoke) for users in Postgres Database.  When i execute the code,  i see no changes in the User Roles. There are no error in python code and no changes in Postgres DB

SuperUser: postgres;
User to be given access: Mick;
Role: test_ro;
User & Roles have already been created earlier.

---

```
from psycopg2 import sql
import psycopg2


def userAccess():
    con = psycopg2.connect(
        user='postgres',
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port='5432',
        database='test',
        password='*******'
    )
    username = 'mick'
    role = 'test_ro'
    query = sql.SQL("GRANT {0} TO {1}").format(
        sql.Identifier(role),
        sql.Identifier(username)
    )
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query.as_string(con))

userAccess()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing out (cur.execute("COMMIT")) at the end. I was able to add the tole for the user successfully.

```
query = sql.SQL("GRANT {0} TO {1}").format(
        sql.Identifier(role),
        sql.Identifier(username)
    )
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query.as_string(con))
    cur.execute("COMMIT")
```